# PowerShell select entry point to append text

Tags: powershell

```
case "10.0.4"
   Response.Redirect ("http://polds03")
case "10.0.6"'
   Response.Redirect ("http://rusds02")
```

I am trying to read in an ASP file that has a bunch of redirects in it. I could use Add-Content to put an entry at the beginning and end of the file but that's not what is needed. When I look at the array I am trying to add between [15..219], preferably alphabetically.

It's a classic ASP file. I need to insert entries. I could randomly select an entry point but whats a better way to handle where to add a new entry?

```
<%
dim ipsubnet(2)
IPAddr = Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")
IPSplit = Split(IPAddr,".")
response.write(IPSplit(2))

ipsubnet(0) = ipsplit(0)
ipsubnet(1) = ipsplit(1)
ipsubnet(2) = ipsplit(2)

Subnet = Join(ipsubnet,".")
response.write(Subnet)

select case Subnet
 case "10.0.4"
   Response.Redirect ("http://asdftFR4")
 case "10.0.6"
   Response.Redirect ("http://ghjrt")
 case "10.0.7"
   Response.Redirect ("http://zxcvasd")
 case "10.8.41"
   Response.Redirect ("http://asdf")
 case "10.0.16"
   Response.Redirect ("http://lqwer")
 case "10.8.32"
   Response.Redirect ("http://xcvbn")
 case "10.8.34"
   Response.Redirect ("http://qwerqwe")
 case "10.0.27"
   Response.Redirect ("http://asdf")
 case "10.8.21"
   Response.Redirect ("http://sfW3FR4")
 case "10.0.29"
   Respons.Redirect ("http://denW3FR3")
 case "10.8.54"
   Response.Redirect ("http://asdfqw")
 case "10.8.50"
   Response.Redirect ("http://dfsg")
 case "10.0.36"
   Response.Redirect ("http://qwerqwer")
 case "10.0.38"
   Response.Redirect ("http://qwer")
 case "10.8.38"
   Response.Redirect ("http://yuioo")
 case "10.6.126"
   Response.Redirect ("http://ghjk")
 case "10.0.68"
   Response.Redirect ("http://nyW3FR3")
 case "10.0.70"
   Response.Redirect ("http://ghkghk")
 case "10.0.71"
   Response.Redirect ("http://ashui")
 case "10.8.24"
   Response.Redirect ("http://ntyuktyf")
 case "10.0.136"
   Response.Redirect ("http://aderty")
 case "10.6.137"
   Response.Redirect ("http://gfhjj")
 case "10.6.138"
   Response.Redirect ("http://asdfasdf")
 case "10.6.139"
   Response.Redirect ("http://chilW3FR3")
 case "10.6.140"
   Response.Redirect ("http://chilW3FR3")
 case "10.6.141"
   Response.Redirect ("http://chilW3FR3")
 case "10.0.117"
   Response.Redirect ("http://chilW3FR3")
 case "10.6.33"
   Response.Redirect ("http://CHRW3FR2")
 case "10.0.138"
   Response.Redirect ("http://laW3FR3")
 case "10.0.139"
   Response.Redirect ("http://laW3FR3")
 case "10.0.162"
   Response.Redirect ("http://dckW3FR3")
 case "10.0.163"
   Response.Redirect ("http://dckW3FR3")
 case "10.0.164"
   Response.Redirect ("http://dckW3FR3")
 case "10.0.165"
   Response.Redirect ("http://dckW3FR3")
 case "10.6.133"
   Response.Redirect ("http://miaW3FR4")
 case "10.0.179"
   Response.Redirect ("http://oakW3FR1")
 case "10.6.62"
   Response.Redirect ("http://bosW3FR2")
 case "10.0.213"
   Response.Redirect ("http://denW3FR3")
 case "10.0.214"
   Response.Redirect ("http://denW3FR3")
 case "10.0.215"
   Response.Redirect ("http://W3FR3")
 case "10.0.234"
   Response.Redirect ("http://QSDFR2")
 case "10.6.5"
   Response.Redirect ("http://3FR2")
 case "10.6.17"
   Response.Redirect ("http://hW3FR4")
 case "10.6.21"
   Response.Redirect ("http://cW3FR4")
 case "10.6.25"
   Response.Redirect ("http://iW3FR4")
 case "10.6.43"
   Response.Redirect ("http://2W3FR1")
 case "10.6.68"
   Response.Redirect ("http://erty36y")
 case "10.0.0"
   Response.Redirect ("PrinterList.htm")  
end select

%>
```

Comment: Can you provide a bigger sample and the code you're currently having problems with?

Comment: By asp file, do you mean like an aspx.cs ?

Comment: If I do Add-Content it will write at the end or beginning of the file. I am trying to parse whats there now to determine where the new entry should go.